# Cant keep the square size equal - bootstrap

Tags: css

I have a simple square block:

```
.coverw-block-welcome{
  height: 27vh;
  background-color: #1b6d85;
  margin:5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```

And i make the position with the next class:

```
col-xs-6 col-sm-3
```

The issue is when I make the screen smaller in the width then the height.
In that situation, the square become a rectangle.

There is a way to keep the proportions of the square even if I reduce the size of the height or the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't have a specified `width` to your square, that is why it becomes a rectangle. Take a look at this code snippet.

```css
.coverw-block-welcome{
  height: 27vh;
  width: 27vh;
  background-color: #1b6d85;
  margin:5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverw-block-welcome"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Responsive Square

```css
.square { 
 background-color: #1b6d85;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 height: 27vh;
 width: 27vh;
}

.square:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the width the same as height in order to scale it proportionally. This code should work.

```
.coverw-block-welcome{
  height: 27vh;
  background-color: #1b6d85;
  width: 27vh;
  margin:15px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```